What are N-Buffers?
For a school project, I had to read a scientific paper that talked about Ambient Occlusion. In it, the authors mentionned using a technique they call N-Buffering. From what I understood, it looks like its talking about blurring images by averaging from samples further and further away, taking advantage of the fact that those samples encode data from their local region, instead of having to fetch that data individually, but I'm not sure and I would like to clarify exactly what they're talking about.
Here's the article: https://graphics.tudelft.nl/Publications-new/2015/KSE15/paper.pdf

Note that the paper you linked identifies the N-buffer concept as being introduced in “N-Buffers for efficient depth map query" by Xavier Décoret. Have you read the source paper, and does that clarify the points you need help with? If not, can you explain your understanding based on this original source, and what parts are still unclear?

Thank you for pointing that out, I didn't see it. Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I understood correctly N-buffers basically repeat an operation on further and further away pixels and stores the result in different levels, a bit like mipmaps and blurring, but every level is the same resolution. Except that the operation doesn't need to be blurring, it can be maxing, or any other convolution matrix. Would you agree with this definition?

While technical graphics questions aren't off topic here, I think that the Computer Graphic Stack Exchange might be a better fit given the academic nature of the paper. Is there a game dev specific aspect of this you're work out?

I didn't know there existed such thing as Computer Graphic Stack Exchange... I'll be sure to check that out, next time!

Here is the description given in paper credited as the source for N-buffers, that being “N-Buffers for efficient depth map query" by Xavier Décoret:

We introduce the N-buffer as a tool for multiresolution depth map representation. This neighborhood buffer encodes the value and position of local depth extrema at different scales in an image cube, in contrast to the image pyramid.
An N-buffer is a sequence of depth maps similar to an image
pyramid [Wil83] except that all levels have the same resolution. Level 0 is a standard depth map. A pixel at level \$i\$
stores the maximum depth of the pixels in a neighborhood of
size \$i\$ in level 0. Different definitions of neighborhood can be
used. For the moment, we define the neighborhood of size \$i\$
of pixel \$(x, y)\$ to be the \$2^i \times 2^i\$
grid of pixels whose lower left
corner is located at \$(x, y)\$.
Figure 1 shows an example of the
four first levels of an N-buffer. Because all levels have the
same resolution, an N-buffer can be built from a depth map
of any size; for this definition of neighborhood, the number
of levels is the log of the largest side of the initial depth map.

Figure 1: (a) Level 0 of an N-buffer is a depth map. (b) A pixel (boxed in red) in level 1 stores the maximum depth of the 2×2
pixels north and east of it (shown on left image). (c) At level 2 it stores the maximum depth of 4×4 pixels (boxed in purple). (d)
At level 3 it stores the maximum depth of 8×8 pixels (boxed in yellow).

So to answer your question:

If I understood correctly, N-buffers basically repeat an operation on further and further away pixels and stores the result in different levels, a bit like mipmaps and blurring, but every level is the same resolution. Except that the operation doesn't need to be blurring, it can be maxing, or any other convolution matrix. Would you agree with this definition?

I'd say there's precedent for this. Later in the N-buffer paper (in section 3.3), Décoret shows a modified N-buffer using a min operation instead of a max. In the paper you linked, Kroes, Schut, and Eisemann further generalize this to use averaging rather than a min or max.
So we might say:
"A neighbourhood buffer (N-buffer) caches the result of applying a given operation over neighbourhoods of varying sizes in a data set. Level 0 contains the original source data. The \$i^{th}\$ level of the N-buffer contains the results of applying the operation over each neighbourhood of size \$i\$ in level 0."
